# How can I fix my Guess The Number game in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making a guess the number game in Python but it just wont work.
I want it to just say guess and then you guess it until its true. Sorry if the solution is so simple because I'm a beginner(I have been learning python for 3 days).

```
import random

while True:
    print("Choose number gap(0-10,0-100)")
    gap = input()

    if gap == "0-10":
        number = random.randint(0,10)
        print("Guess")
        guess = int(input())

        if guess == number:
            print("True the number was: ", number)
        while guess != number:
            print("False")
            guess = int(input())


    if gap == "0-100":
        number = random.randint(0,100)
        print(number)
        guess = int(input())

        if guess == number:
            print("True the number was: ", number)
        while guess != number:
            print("False")
            guess = int(input())
```

Comment: I don't think, it's a good idea to ask here. It's not like your algorithm does not work, because you don't understand the language. Just sit back, grab a piece of paper and a pencil and think about your problem. This way you *learn* programming

Comment: Your code looks fine, just remove "if guess == number:
            print("True the number was: ", number)" statements and place "
            print("True the number was: ", number)" smartly below while loop.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you'll need to use a loop. In this case, a while loop will be used. We'll check to see if the inputted number is equal to the random number. When it's not, the loop will repeat until it is correct, and then repeat the program again.

```
import random

while True:
    print("Choose number gap(0-10,0-100)")
    gap = input()

    if gap == "0-10":
        number = random.randint(0,10)
        print("Guess")
        guess = int(input())

        while guess != number:
            print("False. Guess again")
            guess = int(input())

        print("True the number was: ", number)

    if gap == "0-100":
        number = random.randint(0,100)
        print("Guess")
        guess = int(input())

        while guess != number:
            print("False. Guess again")
            guess = int(input())

        print("True the number was: ", number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `while` first, until true. And you don't have to call input alone first.

```py
import random

while True:
    print("Choose number gap(0-10,0-100)")
    gap = input()
    guess = -1

    if gap == "0-10":
        number = random.randint(0,10)
        print("Guess")

        while guess != number:
            guess = int(input())
            print("False")

        print("True the number was: ", number)


    elif gap == "0-100":
        number = random.randint(0,100)
        print("Guess")

        while guess != number:
            guess = int(input())
            print("False")

        print("True the number was: ", number)
```